# Regex square close bracket

Tags: regex, bash

I can use Bash to match a set of characters

```
$ [[ a =~ [abc] ]]; echo $?
0
```

However if I want a close square bracket `]` to be included in the set, it fails

```
$ [[ a =~ [abc\]] ]]; echo $?
1

$ [[ a =~ [abc\\]] ]]; echo $?
1
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the man page `regex(7)`:

```
To include a literal ']' in the list, make it the first character (fol-
lowing a possible '^').
```

Testing:

```
$ [[ "]" =~ []abc] ]]; echo $?
0
```

Comment: That's interesting.  Why would the order matter inside of a character class?

Comment: @David to avoid having to escape it. Empty character classes are not valid, so in `[]` the `]` cannot be the end of the character class. Therefore it can be treated as a literal character. Similar things go for hyphens (which usually create ranges, unless they are the first or last character) and carets (which negate the character class unless they are not the first character).